# Dymola mos script environment variables

Tags: environment-variables, dymola

Is there a way to use the Windows environment variables in Dymolas `.mos` scripts?
Something like this:

```
// Load libraries, last one determines the working directory
openModel(%USERPROFILE% + "Documents/Dymola/MyTestLib/package.mo");
```

Alternatively, does Dymola know some other predefined pathes? 
I would like to make .mos script a bit more portable to a different PC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `getEnvironmentVariable` function from the MSL.

So this should do what you want:

```
user_profile = Modelica.Utilities.System.getEnvironmentVariable("USERPROFILE", convertToSlash=true);
openModel(user_profile + "/Documents/Dymola/MyTestLib/package.mo");
```

On startup Dymola also defines two useful environment variables:

- DYMOLA: the dymola installation directory, e.g. `C:/Program Files/Dymola 2019 FD01`
- DYMOLAWORK: the startup directory, with `C:/Users/<user>/Documents/Dymola` as default. See user Manual 1 for details.

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I was looking for!