# Dymola mos script: get current directory

Tags: scripting, filepath, dymola

In a mos script, I want to save the current directory (i.e. the directory where the mos script is) to a string variable. In a second step, I want to open a library that is located in a directory net to the mos file.

I tried it like this:

```
myCWD = Modelica.Utilities.System.getWorkDirectory();
```

but this will always have the value `C:\USERNAME\Documents\Dymola`.

Is there a way to get the path of the mos file itself, from within the mos script?
Or are there better ways to use relative paths, or construct absolute paths from a relative path (but always relative to the mos file)?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41832589/how-to-add-load-libraries-change-directory-etc-on-startup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cd`returns Dymolas working directory, so it works as expected. I don't know how to solve your problem with mos scripts, but in a Modelica function the Dymola built in function `classDirectory()` does what you want.

Here is a minimal example:

```
function myScript
algorithm 
  Modelica.Utilities.Streams.print(classDirectory());
end myScript;
```

Note that in Dymola functions can replace mos scripts in most cases. Usually you can simply copy your mos script content to the algorithm section of a function and call the function.

Comment: Maybe my approach was to complicated: What I want to achieve is to load a library from a relative path, so that I can put the load.mos file next to the library on SVN or git, and everybody checking out the repo can just double-click the load.mos file. Any ideas how that can be done?

Comment: I use this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58378134/8725275 (one of the answers in the question you marked as related). The only trouble with that is, that all users have to define an environment variable.