# How to install a new Modelica library in Dymola?

Tags: modelica, dymola

I would like to know:

1. the most efficient way to install a library in Dymola, so that it appears in my list of libraries in File > Libraries.
2. is it possible to have it preloaded in my package browser when I open Dymola, as for instance the Modelica Standard Library?

I would like to install the free library ExternData, using Dymola 2021.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: There are a number of ways to automatically load libraries. Most of them are mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41832589/how-to-add-load-libraries-change-directory-etc-on-startup. It also contains some other hints like changing the working directory etc.

Comment: Ah, thanks @MarkusA. Will add the hints from here to that answer.

Answer (score 2):

Dymola 2021 (and later) has Tools>Library Management>Modelica Path  where you can add the directory *containing* your external libraries.

To make libraries appear preloaded you have to add a `libraryInfo.mos` script in the corresponding library; you can look at Modelica Standard Library in the Dymola installation for inspiration.

The latter is described in more detail in the section "More about libraries and the building of menus of libraries and demo" page 200 in `Dymola User Manual 1A.pdf`.