# How to load libraries during startup in Dymola during startup in Linux

Tags: modelica, dymola

For Dymola linux users: I am using several libraries and I have to painfully load every one of them each time I start Dymola in Linux. In windows, I found some links to enable automatic loading by modifying .mos scripts. Is there any such method to load libraries during startup in in Linux?

Answer (score 1):

Dymola should support the same methods for doing that on Linux as on Windows; see [How to add load libraries, change directory, etc. on startup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41832589/how-to-add-load-libraries-change-directory-etc-on-startup)

The only difference is that if you really use paths in scripts they are different, but normally you shouldn't use them directly.